# Can an object serialized with protobuf-net in c# be deserialized with python by generating a .proto file?

Tags: c#, python, protobuf-net

The issue is that the producer of the data does not have a .proto definition and just has the .cs files.

From looking at other questions it seems it is possible but is there a tool to convert the .cs protobuf-net definition to a .proto file so I can use the file to deserialize in python?

Comment: It would be helpful to show code that you have tried - this will lead to better/faster response to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
string proto = Serializer.GetProto<YourRootType>();
```

Note that if you're using `DateTime` or `TimeSpan`, you should ideally use `DataFormat.WellKnown` - to use `Timestamp` and `Duration` respectively - however, this is a breaking change to your existing data (this is done via the `[ProtoMember(...)]`)